# Google DFP's performClickOnAssetWithKey:customClickHandler does not work with swift

Tags: swift, google-dfp

I want to use DFP with swift.

I'm trying to use `performClickOnAssetWithKey:customClickHandler` method for reporting click.
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/native

But, it doesn't work and the closure doesn't work as well.

Have anyone used this method?

Comment: FYI, It appears that in Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK v7.24.1 this is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer.

GADNativeCustomTemplateAd has variable name `googleClickTrackingURLString`. then we can get the value `nativeCustomTemplateAd.valueForKey("googleClickTrackingURLString")`

And after I accessed the url, clicking report counter ran correctly.

In conclusion, I didn't use `performClickOnAssetWithKey:customClickHandler` method.

Comment: you accessed the url through a call or web browser open ?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen I just called the url. I'm not using web browser open.

Comment: would calling the url in a hidden UIWebView also work? I mean, would the click still count on dfp?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen I think so. You should try and check on dfp dashboard.